# how to save a sin value in a short variable

Tags: c

I want to save the 16 MSB of a sin value in a short variable ,like :

```
short x =0;
x = (short ) (sin(3.14) >> 48 );
```

since the return value of sin in C is a double. but this doesn't work and I just don't get it ! 
is there a way to solve this or do I need an extra function for that

Comment: how did this even compile? `sin(…)` returns a `double`. You can't shift that…

Comment: He said it doesn't work.

Comment: Even if it did work: it should be a *left* shift!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `sin(x)` is *always* within `[-1..1]` range the best you can do is

```
double arg = 3.14; // or whatever
short x = (short) (sin(arg) * 32767); // 32767 is max short
```

restore (when you need *actual* `sin` value)

```
double value = x / 32767.0; // <- note the max short form: ".0"
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is basically stored as fixed point notation.  A quick google search for that will turn up lots of resources that could be helpful.

Comment: Always? No, only if `x` is finite. I also recommend using `SHRT_MAX` instead of `32767`. It's more expressive and doesn't need an additional comment.

Comment: @cremno and then cast on restoring `double value = x / (double)SHRT_MAX;`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `sin(3.14)` is smaller than 1. Only the integer part is passed to x and this is 0.

The right shift of 48 applies to the integer. Right shifting 0 of 48 bits doesn't make it better.

What you could do is the following:

```
x = (short ) (sin(3.14) *1000);
```